# Magnific popup video doesn't open popup but has sound --- I think this is a noconflict issue

Tags: jquery, video, magnific-popup

I added the magnific-popup video code to my site ... the sound of the youtube video plays but there seems to be a noconflict issue with jquery.  When I strip the other jquery includes, I do see the video.  Please let me know if you see a problem with my implementation of noconflict.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
  <noscript>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" />
  </noscript>
 </head>
 <body class="index loading">
 
  <!-- Banner -->  
   <section id="banner">
    
    <div class="inner">
     <footer>
      <ul class="buttons">
       <li><a class="popup-youtube" title="How It Works" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArWEUuZg4n8">how it works</a></li>
      </ul>
     </footer>
    
    </div>
    
   </section>

<!-- Video script - Magnific Popup - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html -->
<script>
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
  disableOn: 700,
  type: 'iframe',
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
  removalDelay: 160,
  preloader: false,

  fixedContentPos: false
 });
});
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here's the link to the page
[test page with broken noconflict](http://blueskyesolutions.com/capstone-redeux/test.html)

The "How it works" link is inside the turquoise box.

Thanks in advance for you help with this troublesome bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

since you called the `.noConflict`

---

But you do not need to call it. There is nothing wrong with your script..

What you need to do is include the magnific popup CSS stylesheet in the `<head>` tag.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: You are exactly right!  I did include the CSS file in the <head> but it was in a <noscript> tag.  I relocated the magnific-popup.css file outside of the <noscript> and the video is working as expected.  Thank you so much!